# Multiple choice probability of passing

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations, binomial-distribution

> A student is given a test consisting of $30$ multiple-choice questions. For each question
> there are $5$ possible answers of which one is correct. To pass, the student must answer at least $25$
> questions correctly. On the first $20$ he knows the answers and for the remaining
> questions he chooses an answer haphazardly and independently. Calculate the probability that he will pass the test.

I solved this problem a few months ago but I forgot how I did it. Does anyone have a better suggestion than what I did?

$$\sum
_{i=0}^5\frac{10!}{\left(5-i\right)!\left(10-\left(5-i\right)\right)!}\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^{5+i}\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^{5-i}=0.03279$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:** Use the [Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). There are $10$ remaining question and the student needs at least $5$ to be guessed correctly. Each question has a fixed probability of success $0.2$. Therefore, we need to find $\mathbb{P}(X \ge 5)$ where $X$~Binomial$(10,0.2)$. This is the same as $1- \mathbb{P}(X < 5)$. To find this probability, you can use the [Cumulative Distribution Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function) for the Binomial Distribution to complete the problem (or you can calculate the sum of the [Probability Mass Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Probability_mass_function) over the values $0$ to $4$ (since the inequality is up to, but not including, the number value $X=5$) .